# 7-Zip command line to extract a folder from an archive

Tags: command-line, console, 7-zip

I'm using the [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) commandline to extract a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) archive called `abc.zip` which is an archive with a folder called 'zipper' with three text files in it (`a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt`).

My problem is when I extract it with the following command:

```
7z e C:\abc\abc.zip -y oC:\abc
```

7-Zip extracts everything, but it doesn't extract the folder 'zipper', it just extracts `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` and puts them in the output destination (that is, `C:\abc`).

How can I make 7-Zip just extract the actual folder?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use `7z x archive.zip` to extract with full paths. See: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract_full.htm

Comment: +1 thought the switch -e would be sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

There should probably be a hyphen in front of the `o`:

```
-oC:\abc
```

Also consider the `-r` option for recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve a similar problem. Here is the code I used. This script receives a folder and unzips all zips (and deletes them afterwards). The trick is to unzip the data into a special folder. A little bit edgy but it works...

```
@echo off

set SEVEN_ZIP_HOME=C:\Program Files\7-Zip

set TEMPDIR=temp

set WORKING_DIR="%1"

if "%WORKING_DIR%"==""  set WORKING_DIR=%~dp0

cd /d %WORKING_DIR%

if not exist %TEMPDIR% md %TEMPDIR%

for %%i in ("%WORKING_DIR%\*.zip") do call :unzipAndDelete "%%i"

rd %TEMPDIR%

goto :end

:unzipAndDelete 

set ZIP_FILE=%~1

call :extractName %ZIP_FILE%

call "%SEVEN_ZIP_HOME%\7z.exe" e "%ZIP_FILE%" -o./%TEMPDIR%

copy .\%TEMPDIR%\*.* %FILENAME%.log

del .\%TEMPDIR%\*.* /q

del "%ZIP_FILE%"

goto :end

:extractName 

set FILENAME=%~n1
goto :end


:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with considering `-r`
The doc explicitly says :-)

> **-r[-|0]**
> Recurse subdirectories (CAUTION: this flag does not do what you think, avoid using it)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).